# I have two AWS hosted zones for my website. One with www and one without, both point to the same nameservers and IP address. Only one of them works

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

Is it correct practice to have two hosted zones for the same site - one with www prefix and the other without? I want either [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) or example.com to reach the same IP address. Finding it hard to get a definitive answer!

Comment: You should have a single hosted zone with records for `www` and one for naked apex (e.g. `example.com` without a subdomain).

Comment: Thanks for the input - I realised that in AWS you you create a CNAME record with the www. prefix, but it's not a separate hosted zone - I think the tutorial I watched lacked the depth needed. Still learning the lingo!